# Is there a name attributed to this type of checkmate pattern?

Tags: checkmate, terminology, patterns

I was going over an old [lichess.com game](https://lichess.org/S82ZiDWr) when I realized that the checkmating pattern seemed familiar.

```
[FEN "5rk1/p4pp1/1p5p/2p4Q/2P3R1/P4q2/6RP/4r2K w - - 0 1"]
```

Here it is boiled down, although the White rook could be replaced by any White piece.

```
[FEN "4k3/8/8/8/8/5q2/6RP/4r2K w - - 0 1"]
```

I wondered if this mating pattern his a particular name. However, Wikipedia is of no help. Is there a name for this checkmating pattern?

Comment: It may count as a special subcase of the back-rank mate.

Comment: @Annatar Yes, maybe mixed with a pin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP had two different patterns.  One is simple mate with two pieces attacking two files.

The other one is just a pin and a back rank rook mate.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ladder mate (along files)
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkmate_pattern#Ladder_mate_(lawnmower_mate)
2. Back-rank mate - the king's escape from the back-rank is impeded by its own pieces. Incorporates an absolute pin immobilising the Rook.
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkmate_pattern#Back-rank_mate

[image]